# bash/sed, replace line in file at same indentation level

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm looking to replace lines in a file. i.e. if "oldtext" is in the file at the start of a line, replace the *whole line* by "newtext".

Start of the line can be `^oldtext` *or* `oldtext` will be indented by some whitespace/tabs

```
grep "^[\S]oldtext" myfile.txt   # doesn't work
```

I need to calculate the same indentation level that "oldtext" had

```
prefixspaces = <number of spaces before the "mytext", converting tabs to 4 spaces>
```

I realise that sed is maybe the best way to achieve this, but I somehow need to calculate the prefix space first, then my output is something like:

```
sed -i -e 's/^$prefixspaces$newtext*$/$prefixspaces$newtext/g' myfile.txt
```

Can't work out how to calculate this. Maybe the `$prefixspace` can be held in a group `()` or something so that sed can easily calculate and work with it? Possibly this is a sed or awk one-liner, but I can't work it out after some searching.

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output too in your question for making it more clear.

Comment: `s/^\([[:space:]]*\)oldtext/\1$newtext/`?

Comment: This is great @Shawn, I added `.*` after oldtext so that it would replace the entire line and wanted any whitespace so changed it to `\s*` at start of line. Works well.

Comment: You should test the answers you got when `oldtext` contains regexp metacharacters and `newtext` contains backreferences. For example try them when `oldtext` is `a.c` and the input file contains both `a.c` and `abc`, and when `newtext` is `d&e`. You should be doing literal string matching and literal string replacements, not regexp matching and backreference-enabled string replacements which are all that sed supports and so far all of the answers do.

Comment: ok, do you have a way that fixes that Ed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed 's/^\( *\)oldtext.*/\1newtext/' file
```

Explanation:

*search*

```
^             beginning of the line
\( *\)        capture 0 or more spaces in group 1
oldtext       'oldtext'
.*            rest of the line
```

*replace*

```
\1            the 0 or more spaces from group1
newtext       'newtext'
```

Answer (score 2):

### With `sed`

Another way to do, additionaly to the accepted answer, is using class characters ([[:space:]]), and extender regular expressions with the `-r` parameter:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([[:space:]]*)oldtext.*/\1newtext/' << _eof
  oldtext this
 a
    oldtext also this
_eof
```

And the result will be:

```
  newtext
 a
    newtext
```

In `([[:space:]]*)`, we captured a group with zero or more spaces, but we can specify a certain number.

### With `awk`

We can use `gsub` to replace spaces and count the times:

```
$ awk \
    -v old="oldtext" \
    -v new="newtext" \
    'BEGIN{re="^[[:space:]]*"old}
{
  if (match($0,re)) {
    i=gsub(/ /,"")
    while (--i) printf " "
    print new
  }
  else 
    print
}' << _eof
  oldtext this
oldtext also this
    oldtext and this
  oldtext also this
_eof
```

And the result will be:

```
  newtext
 newtext
     newtext
   newtext
```

### With `perl`

We can achieve this with the use of `perl` in a *sed-like* style:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/^(\s*)oldtext.*/\1newtext/' << _eof
  oldtext this
oldtext this
    oldtext this
  oldtext also this
_eof
```

And the result will be:

```
  newtext
newtext
    newtext
  newtext
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*oldtext/s/\S.*/newtext/' file
```

Match `oldtext` at the start of a line or indented and replace from the first non-white space character.